# How can I convert a TIMESTAMP_MICROS to date format?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to BigQuery. I am trying to convert a TIMEASTAMP_MICROS value to Date format but it is giving the wrong converted value.

Query:

---

```
SELECT prod_timestamp,TIMESTAMP_MICROS(prod_timestamp) as t1,FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%d-%m-%Y',TIMESTAMP_MICROS(prod_timestamp))  AS Test_Prod_Stamp_Date FROM table
```

Result:

> prod_timestamp     |   t1                     |          Test_Prod_Stamp_Date
>
> 1606775685759680  |  2020-12-01 04:04:45.759+05:30 |   30-11-2020

'2020-12-01' changed to '30-11-2020' which is causing error.

Please help to understand the error .

Comment: you should double check your output - the one presented in question is not what is really gets output - t1 is `2020-11-30 22:34:45.759680 UTC` which is correctly "converted" into respective date - so something wrong with your question I think

Comment: I have tried again but it is giving the same result.

I am using PLX Script with Engine 'Dremel' and Dialect 'GoogleSQL'.

Answer (score 0):

The t1 seems to be not on UTC, but on UTC+05:30 as I can see in your output. In other words there is only one timestamp, expressed in two different timezones, however your sql statement and the output don't align.

When trying the following it looks consistent

```
SELECT 
   1606775685759680, 
   TIMESTAMP_MICROS(1606775685759680) as t1, 
   FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%d-%m-%Y',TIMESTAMP_MICROS(1606775685759680)) AS Test_Prod_Stamp_Date
```

Output:

| Row | f0_ | t1 | Test_Prod_Stamp_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1606775685759680 | 2020-11-30 22:34:45.759680 UTC | 30-11-2020 |

If you consistently use `TIMESTAMP_MICROS`  you will always get UTC, but you can also give the timezone as a parameter, i.e.

```
DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(1606775685759680), "UTC")
DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(1606775685759680), "America/Los_Angeles")
```